# What could have caused a short circuit on a power adapter?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, short-circuit

So, I've got a device without a power cable. I've found and used a old one I've found lying around.
After getting the device to work, it started to smoke... What could have gone wrong?

Here are some details on the cable and the adapter:
Input: 100~240V 50/60Hz 2.5A MAX
Output: 12V = 7.5A

The cable got only it's model nr and 10A~

What could have caused the short circuit (smoke) in the adapter?

Comment: Are you asking if that adapter will set every single device on earth on fire, or did you have a specific device in mind?

Comment: Well it's an Antminer U3. I did everything the manual told but the power adapter started to short cut and smoke. The antminer was not damaged.
It would be great to know if this could have caused by the cable I used

Comment: What is an Antminer U3? Do you expect us to know every product on earth or google it for you? Please provide every relevant  links/photos/data in your question.

Comment: Why do you want to know about the product. It's a general question and I'd like to know what may have caused this

Comment: Whatever you connected to the power-supply *is* part of the failure mode of the power supply. You claim it is a general question and you ask "What could have caused the short circuit in the adapter?". Well, the *general answer* is "whatever you connected to it" (assuming the cable and the supply weren't faulty beforehand). As it stands, the question is underspecified and too broad.

Comment: Well you're right, it's not that easy if all you know is - you plug a device and it works. I thought the cable and the adapter might be incompatible or something. The cable and the supply worked well before and I dont think any of them could be faulty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely the device you plugged in tried to draw more current than the AC adapter could provide. A well built one wouldn't start smoking, but clearly this one wasn't well built.

When looking for an adapter for a device, you need to make sure it provides a voltage within the range specified on the device, and a current at least as high as it specifies.

Comment: The device I mentioned has voltage control in it's software. So that could be it. I ran it within min and max given in it's manual over here
https://www.bitmaintech.com/files/download/AntMiner-U3%20user%20guide.pdf
There was some more devices plugged in the outlet (used an extension cord), so it could be the case. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I assume you're talking about control over the core voltage of the FPGA. That's not relevant to what input voltage it takes.

Comment: Ooh, yes I was talking about that. 
So I guess 
 - the outlet gave it's max, but that was not enough or
 - could it be that the adapter is not functioning properly?
Would it be safe to try it again on an other outlet without burning up the whole house?

Comment: If the adapter's emitted smoke, cut the cord off and throw it away. Then try again with a new adapter that is definitely rated to at least the current required.